# GitHub API Ping

Tags: authorization, github-api

What is the best way to ping the GitHub API to ensure that a user's credentials are valid?  I would like to simply call the API while passing the credentials via Basic Auth.  I cannot find a suitable docile request that requires credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify an OAuth token you can use this endpoint:

http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#check-an-authorization

To verify a username-password pair - just try making any API request with Basic Auth (e.g. just make a request to https://api.github.com):

http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

However, notice that making a few requests with a bad username-password pair will temporarily lock you out if those are made within a short period. Providing a separate endpoint for verifying username-password pairs that doesn't have this lock-out feature would be a security risk.